# NullPointerException on network connection

Tags: android, spring, android-networking

I have a null pointer when I try to do a network exchange using Spring for Android

Stack trace:

```
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225): 21:25:54.169 pool-2-thread-1 An exception occured during request network execution :null
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:62)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:476)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:438)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:414)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at com.xxx.xxx.rest.SongPostRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(SongPostRequest.java:43)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at com.xxx.xxx.rest.SongPostRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(SongPostRequest.java:1)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:26)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at com.octo.android.robospice.request.RequestProcessor.processRequest(RequestProcessor.java:214)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at com.octo.android.robospice.request.RequestProcessor$1.run(RequestProcessor.java:146)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-28 21:25:54.164: E//RequestProcessor.java:226(5225):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

And the `SongPostRequest` where the stack trace is in:

```
@Override
public Response loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json"));
    requestHeaders.set("Userid", String.valueOf(user.getId()));
    HttpEntity<ListenedSong> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<ListenedSong>(
            requestHeaders);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();

    try {
        ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://192.168.1.117/Project56/web/app_dev.php/mobile/music_new", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Response.class);
        return response.getBody();
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

The response coming from the server gets a status code (200), so I don't get why it is null there?
It looks like the `SimpleClientHttpResponse` from the library I use has a bug. Anyone know more about this?